# Braintree NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, braintree, braintree-sandbox

In the following script I take advantage of the [Braintree JS API](https://braintree.github.io/braintree-web/3.8.0/Client.html#request) to try and tokenize their Sandbox valid credit card info. However, I am met with the error:

```
/..../js/braintree.js:25
          clientInstance.request({
                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'request' of undefined
    at /..../js/braintree.js:25:25
    at null._onTimeout (/..../js/node_modules/braintree-web/lib/deferred.js:9:10)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:92:15)
```

Indicating that my clientInstance is undefined. Can someone help me notice what I am missing?

```
var createClient = require('braintree-web/client').create;


function generateNonce(generatedToken, ccnum, cccvv, ccexp, postal) {
createClient({
          authorization: generatedToken
      }, function (createErr, clientInstance) {
          var data = {
              creditCard: {
                  number: ccnum,
                  cvv: cccvv,
                  expirationDate: ccexp,
                  billingAddress: {
                      postalCode: postal
                  },
                  options: {
                      validate: false
                  }
              }
          };
          // Warning: For a merchant to be eligible for the easiest level of PCI compliance (SAQ A),
          // payment fields cannot be hosted on your checkout page.
          // For an alternative to the following, use Hosted Fields.
          clientInstance.request({
              endpoint: 'payment_methods/credit_cards',
              method: 'post',
              data: data
          }, function (requestErr, response) {
              // More detailed example of handling API errors: https://codepen.io/braintree/pen/MbwjdM
              if (requestErr) { throw new Error(requestErr); }

              console.log('Got nonce:', response.creditCards[0].nonce);
              this.onRetrieval(response.creditCards[0].nonce);
            });
        });
}

generateNonce("valid-client-token", "4111111111111111", "123", "10/20", "1337");
```

Comment: Is there anything on createErr?

Comment: createErr: Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'host' of undefined. Sounds like an issue with their API, right? I don't define 'host' anywhere.

Comment: I would debug createClient to find out what's going on

Comment: Any findings @Syncretic?